# How FlushMode.COMMIT works

Tags: java, hibernate

As per [Session.setFlushMode(FlushMode)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#setFlushMode(org.hibernate.FlushMode)) we can set FlushMode to the session. Now I am trying to test how the [Flushmode.COMMIT](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#COMMIT) mode works with a small example.

I have created an entity called `Cat` with just 2 properties `id` and `name`. Now here is the code that I am testing:

```
    Session session = getSession();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Cat cat = (Cat) session.get(Cat.class, 1);
    cat.setName(name);
    session.flush();
    //tx.commit();
    session.close();
```

From logs I can see that when the line `session.flush()` is executed then hibernate is issuing JDBC update call to database as:

```
Hibernate: update Cat set name=? where id=?
```

As I set the FlushMode to COMMIT, I am expecting that the `update` query will be executed only when I say `tx.commit()` but the flushing is happening at `session.flush()`. Can someone please explain why it is happening like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the Javadoc of `Session#flush()`.

> Force this session to flush. Must be called at the end of a unit of
>   work, before committing the transaction and closing the session
>   (depending on flush-mode, **`Transaction.commit()` calls this method**).

or the javadoc for `FlushMode#MANUAL`

> **The `Session` is only ever flushed when `Session.flush()` is explicitly
>   called by the application.** This mode is very efficient for read only
>   transactions.

Setting a `FlushMode` simply defines when `flush()` will happen automatically (all but `MANUAL`). If you call `flush()` yourself, manually, you're overriding that behavior.